# What does "use exponentially distributed inter-arrival times, but make inter-arrival time 25" mean?

Tags: queueing-theory

I'm asked to simulate inter-arrival times from exp-distribution and then I'm given that inter-arrival times must be 25, 40, 20, 40. I think these mean "average inter-arrival time", so does that mean that I must take (since the mean of exp-distr. is $\lambda^{-1}$) $\frac{1}{\lambda}=25$ and solve for $\lambda$? Then use this for drawing the times?

Comment: Do you have any more context?

Comment: Any chance you could add that (and any other info/attempts) you have to the question?